# JQuery Callback after multiple functions

Tags: jquery, callback

I have seperated HTML files in my project which I load into a main page.

```
$("#tabs-1").load("tab1.html");
$("#tabs-2").load("tab2.html");
$("#tabs-3").load("tab3.html");
```

This function is asynchronous so I need a callback statement after these three fragments have been loaded. I only know how to use a callback for 1 function, not all 3. Here is the workaround I had in mind, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

```
$("#tabs-1").load("tab1.html", function(){
   $("#tabs-2").load("tab2.html", function(){
       $("#tabs-3").load("tab3.html", function(){
           doCallback();
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Fact is I have more than 3 fragments so I'm looking for a cleaner way

Comment: Also in this example the fragments aren't loaded together but 1 by 1.

Comment: so you want them to all be loading at once and when they are finished, but only all of them, to then do the callback?

Comment: Correct. Only at once if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.load()` does not return a `jqXHR` object and so cannot be directly used with `$.when`. What you can easily do, however, is to replace `.load()` with an equivalent `.get()` and then use the `Deferred` / `Promise` strategy:

```
var req1 = $.get("tab1.html", function(data) {
    $("#tabs-1").html(data);
});
var req2 = $.get("tab2.html", function(data) {
    $("#tabs-2").html(data);
});
var req3 = $.get("tab3.html", function(data) {
    $("#tabs-3").html(data);
});
$.when(req1, req2, req3).then(doCallback);
```

Or, you can maintain the `Deferred`s yourself (untested!):

```
var d1 = $.Deferred(),
    d2 = $.Deferred(),
    d3 = $.Deferred();
$("#tabs-1").load("tab1.html", function() { d1.resolve(); });
$("#tabs-2").load("tab2.html", function() { d2.resolve(); });
$("#tabs-3").load("tab3.html", function() { d3.resolve(); });
$.when(d1, d2, d3).then(doCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

The load() function cannot be used in this case because it doesn't return the promise object

```
function load(el, path){
    return $.get(path, function(html){
        $(el).html(html)
    })
}

var l1 = load("#tabs-1", "tab1.html");
var l2 = load("#tabs-2", "tab2.html");
var l3 = load("#tabs-3", "tab3.html");
$.when(l1, l2, l3).then(function(){
    doCallback();
})
```

Comment: `.load()` does not return a `jqXHR` object. Will this work none the less or should `.load()` be replaced by `.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion - to make it clear:

1) create  jquery prototype function for the easy-read interface

```
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        my_load: function(what) {
            var my_this = this;
            return $.get(what, function(data) {
                my_this.html(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

2) use it like this

```
        $.when(
            $("#page_1").my_load("page_1.php"),
            $("#page_2").my_load("page_2.php")
        ).then(function() {
            console.log("all loaded");
            // extra code here
        });
```

I've tested it in Chrome and in IE-11 with jquery-2.0.2